# Update dinâmico com verificação de variáveis $_POST

Tags: php

Estou com um problema. Estou montando um update dinâmico, mas não estou conseguindo montar na query a parte dos **parâmetros a serem atualizados**. Segue o código abaixo para ficar claro o que preciso:

```
function UpdateCommand($table, $params, $id){
        $database = new Database();
        $database->database_connect();

        $select = "SELECT * FROM {$table}";

        $resultselect = mysqli_query($database->database_connect(), $select);
        // Aqui não consigo dar sequência

        $query = "UPDATE {$table} SET {$params} WHERE id_{$table} = $id";
        echo $query;
        //$result = mysqli_query($database->database_connect(), $query);

        $database->database_close_connection(); 
    }
```

Esse update, serviria para qualquer tabela, que seria informada no parâmetro. O mesmo aconteceria com o id. O problema ficou na parte dos campos a serem atualizados. E duas coisas me dificultaram nisso.

1ª- Cada tabela pode ter quantidade de colunas diferentes, então pensei em montar um select para pegar essas colunas e depois usá-las com as variáveis informadas pelo formulário, porém, não consegui fazer isso.

2ª - Mesmo que eu extraia de maneira correta as colunas da tabela, como eu iria dar um `SET` nelas para cada coluna? Isso ficou um pouco confuso para mim.

Esqueci de colocar que eu precisaria fazer uma verificação das variáveis $_POST que foram setadas. Mas esse item aqui é menos relevante, o que importa mais é o update.

Answer (score 0):

## Obtendo o nome das colunas de uma tabela

```
$result = mysqli_query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM nome_da_tabela");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $data[] = $row;
}
print_r($data);
```

## Setar os valores

Daqui para frente precisa adotar algum padrão para que os dados sejam compatíveis com as colunas.

Vamos supor que os dados estejam num array simples.

```
$dados = array('valor 1', 'valor 2', 'valor 3');
```

Para facilitar, os nomes das colunas devem estar também num array simples e exatamente na mesma posição de seus respectivos valores

```
$colunas = array('coluna_do_valor_1', 'coluna_do_valor_2', 'coluna_do_valor_3');
```

Então basta iterar ambos os arrays para montar a query SQL:

```
foreach ($colunas as $k => $v) {
    $params[] = $v." = '".$dados[$k]."'";
}
$params = implode(', ', $params);

$query = "UPDATE {$table} SET {$params} WHERE id_{$table} = $id";
```

Note que deve ter alguns cuidados básicos com essa lógica apresentada na pergunta pois precisa ter um padrão para campos do tipo auto incremento, normalmente o id da tabela. Como é auto incremento, não poderá ser setado no update.

<sub>Sou contra o que pretende fazer. Contudo, me abstenho em opinar e optei pela forma mais objetiva.</sub>

Comment: Daniel, tem algum outro jeito melhor para fazer isso por uma função?

Comment: Não tem função nativa para fazer todos esses processos. Crie a sua própria como já está fazendo.  Apenas demonstrei como fazer. Basta adaptar para dentro da função que está criando.